# Computing the sum of signatures of permutations (pfaffian).

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, permutations

This question is motivated by the definition of pfaffian.

Let $n$ be a nonnegative integer. Let $\Pi$ be the subset of the symmetric group $S_{2n}$ consisting of those permutations $\pi$ that can be written in the form
$$
\pi=\left[\begin{array}{ccccccc}
{1} & {2} & {3} & {4} & {\cdots} & {2 n-1} & {2 n} \\
{i_{1}} & {j_{1}} & {i_{2}} & {j_{2}} & {\cdots} & {i_{n}} & {j_{n}}
\end{array}\right]
$$
(two-line notation)
with $i_{k}<j_{k}, \forall k$, and $i_{1}<i_{2}<\cdots<i_{n}$.

> How to compute the number
>   $\sum_{\pi \in \Pi} \operatorname{sgn}\left(\pi\right)
> $?

Note that the elements of $\Pi$ are precisely the permutations $\pi_\alpha$ in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfaffian#Formal_definition .

Comment: For $n \le 5$ the sum is $1$.

Comment: and for general?

Comment: Okay. The sum is always $1$. Hint: The permutations in $\Pi$ are in bijection with the perfect matchings of the set $\left\{1,2,\ldots,2n\right\}$ (that is, the set partitions of this set into $2$-element blocks). Each perfect matching $M$ has a *crossing number* $\operatorname{xing}M$ (defined to be the number of unordered pairs of crossing blocks in $M$, where we treat the blocks of $M$ as diagonals/edges of a regular $2n$-gon). The permutation $\pi \in \Pi$ corresponding to this matching $M$ satisfies $\operatorname{sgn}\left(\pi\right) = \left(-1\right)^{\operatorname{xing} M}$ (this ...

Comment: ... is not hard to check). Thus, it remains to prove that the sum of $\left(-1\right)^{\operatorname{xing} M}$ over all perfect matchings $M$ of $\left\{1,2,\ldots,2n\right\}$ is $1$. To do so, we define a perfect matching to be *special* if it is $\left\{\left\{1,2\right\},\left\{3,4\right\},\ldots,\left\{2n-1,2n\right\}\right\}$, and to be *non-special* otherwise. Thus, we need to show that the sum of $\left(-1\right)^{\operatorname{xing} M}$ over all non-special perfect matchings $M$ of $\left\{1,2,\ldots,2n\right\}$ is $0$. This is clearly a case for sign-reversing involutions. Here ...

Comment: is one: If $M$ is a non-special perfect matching of $\left\{1,2,\ldots,2n\right\}$, then we pick the smallest $i$ such that $2i-1$ is not matched to $2i$ in $M$ (this exists because $M$ is not special), and swap the partners of $2i-1$ and $2i$. This is clearly an involution on the set of non-special perfect matchings, and it clearly flips the sign of $\left(-1\right)^{\operatorname{xing} M}$. Actually, it's probably easiest if you restate this argument in terms of $\Pi$; the matchings were most likely a detour.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: Why did you write three long comments with continuations instead of an answer?

Comment: @joriki: because that answer would be severely lacking details and prevent others from writing better answers.